# How to find files with predefined extensions while looping through folders and sub folders?

Tags: file, jmeter, directory, subdirectory

I'm new to jmeter. Can you advise me how to loop through folder and its' sub folders in order to write down path to files with predefined extensions.
File extensions will be given as array. Path to files should be, preferably, saved in array as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example solution using [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) and [FileUtils.listFiles()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean)) 
method

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;              

String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String[] extensions = {"xml"};


Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(path).getParentFile(), extensions, true);

for (File file : files) {
    log.info(file.getAbsolutePath());               
}
```

The above code prints all files with `.xml` extension found recursively in JMeter installation folder to *jmeter.log* file.

[image: Printing file names with Beanshell]

Instead of printing file names into the log you can add them to [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using `vars` shorthand for later reuse in the test. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information regarding using scripting in JMeter, using Beanshell for it and examples of using JMeter and Java APIs from Beanshell test elements.

Comment: I should write each extension as a separate item of extensions array, If I want files with more then one extensions??